# Nested loop with increasing number of elements

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I have a longitudinal dataset of 18 time periods. For reasons not to be discussed here, this dataset is in the **wide** shape, not in the **long** one. More precisely, time-varying variables have an **alphabetic prefix** which identifies the time it belongs to. For the sake of this question, consider a quantity of interest called `pay`. This variable is denoted `apay` in the first period, `bpay` in the second, and so on, until `rpay`.

Importantly, different observations have missing values in this variable in different periods, in an unpredictable way. In consequence, running a panel for the full number of periods will reduce my number of observations considerably. Hence, I would like to know precisely how many observations a panel with different lengths will have. To evaluate this, I want to create variables that, **for each period and for each number of consecutive periods** count how many respondents have the variable with that time sequence. For example, I want the variable `b_count_2` to count how many observations have nonmissing `pay` in the first period and the second. This can be achieved with something like this:

```
local b_count_2 = 0
if apay != . & bpay != . {
        local b_count_2 = `b_count_2' + 1 // update for those with nonmissing pay in both periods
    }
```

Now, since I want to do this automatically, this has to be in a loop. Moreover, there are different numbers of sequences for each period. For example, for the third period, there are two sequences (those with pay in period 2 and 3, and those with sequences in period 1, 2 and 3). Thus, the number of variables to create is 1+2+3+4+...+17 = 153. This variability has to be reflected in the loop. I propose a code below, but there are bits that are wrong, or of which I'm unsure, as highlighted in the comments.

```
local list b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r               // periods over which iterate
foreach var of local list {                 // loop over periods
    local counter = 1                   // counter to update; reflects sequence length 
    while `counter' > 0 {                   // loop over sequence lengths
        gen _`var'_counter_`counter' = 0        // generate variable with counter
        if `var'pay != . {              // HERE IS PROBLEM 1. NEED TO MAKE THIS TO CHECK CONDITIONS WITH INCREASING NUMBER OF ELEMENTS 
            recode _`var'_counter_`counter' (0 = 1) // IM NOT SURE THIS IS HOW TO UPDATE SPECIFIC OBSERVATIONS.
            local counter = `counter' - 1       // update counter to look for a longer sequence in the next iteration
        }
    }
    local counter = `counter' + 1               // HERE IS PROBLEM 2. NEED TO STOP THIS LOOP! Otherwise counter goes to infinity.
}
```

An example of the result of the above code (if right) is the following. Consider a dataset of five observations, for four periods (denoted a, b, c, and d):

```
Obs   a  b  c  d
1     1  1  .  1
2     1  1  .  .
3     .  .  1  1
4     .  1  1  .
5     1  1  1  1
```

where 1 means value is observed in that period, and . is not. The objective of the code is to create 1+2+3=6 new variables such that the new dataset is:

```
Obs   a  b  c  d  b_count_2  c_count_2  c_count_3  d_count_2  d_count_3  d_count_4
1     1  1  .  1      1          0          0          0          0          0
2     1  1  .  .      1          0          0          0          0          0
3     .  .  1  1      0          0          0          1          0          0
4     .  1  1  .      0          1          0          0          0          0
5     1  1  1  1      1          1          1          1          1          1
```

Now, why is this helpful? Well, because now I can run a set of `summarize` commands to get a very nice description of the dataset. The code to print this information in one go would be something like this:

```
local list a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r                  // periods over which iterate
foreach var of local list {                         // loop over periods
    local list `var'_counter_*                      // group of sequence variables for each period
    foreach var2 of local list {                        // loop over each element of the list
        quietly sum `var'_counter_`var2' if `var'_counter_`var2' == 1   // sum the number of individuals with value = 1 with sequence of length var2 in period var
        di as text "Wave `var' has a sequence of length `var2' with " as result r(N) as text " observations." // print result
    }
}
```

For the above example, this produces the following output:

```
"Wave 'b' has a sequence of length 2 with 3 observations."
"Wave 'c' has a sequence of length 2 with 2 observations."
"Wave 'c' has a sequence of length 3 with 1 observations."
"Wave 'd' has a sequence of length 2 with 2 observations."
"Wave 'd' has a sequence of length 3 with 1 observations."
"Wave 'd' has a sequence of length 4 with 1 observations."
```

This gives me a nice summary of the trade-offs I'm having between a wider panel and a longer panel.

Comment: Is there any reason not to `reshape long`, do the calculations more easily, and then merge back to your original dataset?

Comment: Well, not a strong one really. Just the way I work. Do you see a way to solve it in the long format? If so, tell me and I will edit the question to allow for that answer. I actually tried to think of a way to solve it using the long format but I could not come up with something. Perhaps it would be a combination of `by`'s and `if`'s but I'm not an expert on Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing this with data in wide form, it is very inefficient to create extra variables just to count patterns of missing values. You can create a single string variable that contains the pattern for each observation. Then, it's just a matter of extracting from this pattern variable what you are looking for (i.e. patterns of consecutive periods up to the current wave). You can then loop over lengths of the matching patterns and do counts. Something like:

```
* create some fake data
clear
set seed 12341
set obs 10
foreach pre in a b c d e f g {
    gen `pre'pay = runiform() if runiform() < .8
}

* build the pattern of missing data
gen pattern = ""
foreach pre in a b c d e f g {
    qui replace pattern = pattern + cond(mi(`pre'pay), " ", "`pre'")
}
list

qui foreach pre in b c d e f g {
    noi dis "{hline 80}" _n as res "Wave `pre'"

    // the longest substring without a space up to the wave
    gen temp = regexs(1) if regexm(pattern, "([^ ]+`pre')")
    noi tab temp

    // loop over the various substring lengths, from 2 to max length
    gen len = length(temp)
    sum len, meanonly
    local n = r(max)
    forvalues i = 2/`n' {
        count if length(temp) >= `i'
        noi dis as txt "length = " as res `i' as txt " obs = " as res r(N)
    }
    drop temp len
}
```

If you are open to working in long form, then here is how you would identify spells with contiguous data and how to loop to get the info you want (the data setup is exactly the same as above):

```
* create some fake data in wide form
clear
set seed 12341
set obs 10
foreach pre in a b c d e f g {
    gen `pre'pay = runiform() if runiform() < .8
}

* reshape to long form
gen id = _n
reshape long @pay, i(id) j(wave) string

* identify spells of contiguous periods
egen wavegroup = group(wave), label 
tsset id wavegroup  
tsspell, cond(pay < .)
drop if mi(pay)

foreach pre in b c d e f g {
    dis "{hline 80}" _n as res "Wave `pre'"

    sum _seq if wave == "`pre'", meanonly
    local n = r(max)
    forvalues i = 2/`n' {
        qui count if _seq >= `i' & wave == "`pre'"
        dis as txt "length = " as res `i' as txt " obs = " as res r(N)
    }

}
```

Comment: I will look into this as soon as I can. By the way, I do not insist on using the wide format. It's just I cannot think on a way to obtain the information required using the long format. I'm happy to look at solution using the long dataset.

Comment: Note that the second example here is entirely consistent with using `tsspell` from SSC, as I recommended, as the `spellid` and `len` variables here are exactly those automatically created by `tsspell` as `_spell` and `_seq`. You just need `egen wavegroup = group(wave)` followed by `tsset id wavegroup` and `tsspell, cond(!missing(pay))`,

Comment: I updated my long form solution to use `tsspell` since you are likely to `tsset` this data anyway.

Comment: Wow, this works flawlessly! +1 for `cond(x,a,b,c)`, didn't know that one. I see now that `tsspell` does the trick, but it would have taken me days to figure out the code. Now, if I may add a request. It would be helpful to find the spell that gives the longest sequence for each length (2, 3, 4, ...), which is in the end what I'm looking for. For example, in the wide case, inside the `forvalues` I add `gen 'pre'len'n' = len`. Then, at the end I add another `foreach` over `n`, which compares all `'pre'len` at that `n` and finds the max, using the `cond()` function. Could you add that bit please?

Comment: Please ask a new question about finding the longest spell. That could be of interest to several others and it would otherwise be buried here.

Comment: But you'd need to sharpen up the problem. The longest sequence of length 2 is of length 2 if it exists, and so forth. What if there are two or more such sequences. The problem would need to be tightly specified.

Answer (score 2):

I echo @Dimitriy V. Masterov in genuine puzzlement that you are using this dataset shape. It can be convenient for some purposes, but for panel or longitudinal data such as you have, working with it in Stata is at best awkward and at worst impracticable.

First, note specifically that

```
local b_count_2 = 0
if apay != . & bpay != . {
        local b_count_2 = `b_count_2' + 1 // update for those with nonmissing pay in both periods
}
```

will only ever be evaluated in terms of the first observation, i.e. as if you had coded

```
if apay[1] != . & bpay[1] != .
```

This is documented [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/). Even if it is what you want, it is not usually a pattern for others to follow.

Second, and more generally, I haven't tried to understand all of the details of your code, as what I see is the creation of a vast number of variables even for tiny datasets as in your sketch. For a series *T* periods long, you would create a triangular number [(*T* - 1)*T*]/2 of new variables; in your example (17 x 18)/2 = 153. If someone had series 100 periods long, they would need 4950 new variables.

Note that because of the first point just made, these new variables would pertain with your strategy only to individual variables like `pay` **and** individual panels. Presumably that limitation to individual panels could be fixed, but the main idea seems singularly ill-advised in many ways. In a nutshell, what strategy do you have to work with these hundreds or thousands of new variables except writing yet more nested loops?

Your main need seems to be to identify spells of non-missing and missing values. There is easy machinery for this long since developed. General principles are discussed [in this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029) and an implementation is downloadable from SSC as `tsspell`.

On Statalist, people are asked to provide workable examples with data as well as code. See [this FAQ](http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata) That's entirely equivalent to long-standing requests here for [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Despite all that advice, I would start by looking at the Stata command `xtdescribe` and associated `xt` tools already available to you. These tools do require a long data shape, which `reshape` will provide for you.

Comment: To be clear, the dataset comes in the wide format, and I do reshape the dataset later, after some cleaning and pre-analysis. My aim is to characterise the number of observations available for all possible consecutive sequences. It could be that it is easier to be solved in the long format.

Comment: (cont) I don't see how the `tsspell` can be helpful to create a summary of observations available for all possible sequences. I have tried to run a few lines but I can't make it work. Note that I do need to differentiate between a spell in period `a b c` and that in period `m n o`. Their common length (3 periods) is not enough (so running a summarise of _spell is not helpful). In fact, the information I am looking for **is contained in 153 values**, and so I cannot see how three variables (_spell, _seq, _end) can fully characterise my dataset. Any hint in that direction could help.

Comment: My view, which is based on experience with Stata as well as your question, is that your wide structure and strategy of adding explosively to the number of variables is in no sense a good approach. Let me emphasise once more my closing advice to look at `xtpattern`. I diagnose here the XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You have thought up an approach and are asking how to take it further, but all experienced Stata advice will be that the approach is misguided. I can't see that you need 153 variables to characterise 18 values!

Comment: I added an example to the post with the type of outcome I am trying to get. `xtpattern` returns a string, which by itself is not enough. From the set of strings I would have to extract statistics about sequences of ones **and their position** (since I don't mind running the panel for `a` to `d` instead of `b` to `e`). That is an alternative method to the one I am attempting, but it also involves a loop over characters in a string. By no means I see how it is totally superior to my approach. Same with `tsspell`. It does not produce my outcome as it is. If that is not true, please indicate.

Comment: Apologies, I meant `xtdescribe`. I'll add another answer. Sorry if it disappoints or does not match your expectations, but I don't feel obliged to give the same advice more than twice.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add another answer based on the example now added to the question.

```
Obs   a  b  c  d
1     1  1  .  1
2     1  1  .  .
3     .  .  1  1
4     .  1  1  .
5     1  1  1  1
```

The aim of this answer is not to provide what the OP asks but to indicate how many simple tools are available to look at patterns of non-missing and missing values, none of which entail the creation of large numbers of extra variables or writing intricate code based on nested loops for every new question. Most of those tools require a `reshape long`.

```
. clear  

. input a b c d

             a          b          c          d
  1.  1 1 . 1
  2.  1 1 . .
  3.  . . 1 1
  4.  . 1 1 .
  5.  1 1 1 1
  6. end 

. rename (a b c d) (y1 y2 y3 y4) 

. gen id = _n 

. reshape long y, i(id) j(time) 
(note: j = 1 2 3 4)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        5   ->      20
Number of variables                   5   ->       3
j variable (4 values)                     ->   time
xij variables:
                           y1 y2 ... y4   ->   y
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtset id time 
       panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  time, 1 to 4
                delta:  1 unit

. preserve 

. drop if missing(y) 
(7 observations deleted)

. xtdescribe 

      id:  1, 2, ..., 5                                      n =          5
    time:  1, 2, ..., 4                                      T =          4
           Delta(time) = 1 unit
           Span(time)  = 4 periods
           (id*time uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         2       2       2         2         3       4       4

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+---------
        1     20.00   20.00 |  ..11
        1     20.00   40.00 |  .11.
        1     20.00   60.00 |  11..
        1     20.00   80.00 |  11.1
        1     20.00  100.00 |  1111
 ---------------------------+---------
        5    100.00         |  XXXX

* ssc inst xtpatternvar 
. xtpatternvar, gen(pattern) 

* ssc inst groups 
. groups pattern

  +------------------------------------+
  | pattern   Freq.   Percent     % <= |
  |------------------------------------|
  |    ..11       2     15.38    15.38 |
  |    .11.       2     15.38    30.77 |
  |    11..       2     15.38    46.15 |
  |    11.1       3     23.08    69.23 |
  |    1111       4     30.77   100.00 |
  +------------------------------------+

. restore  

. egen npresent = total(missing(y)), by(time)

. tabdisp time, c(npresent) 

----------------------
     time |   npresent
----------+-----------
        1 |          2
        2 |          1
        3 |          2
        4 |          2
----------------------
```

Comment: I'm sorry to insist, but none of these tools help me. The `pattern` example with four time periods is simple. Yet, imagine with 18 time periods. More importantly, that command categorises sequences like `11.1` and `1111` differently, which in a panel considering the first two periods are both included. This is why in my method both sequences are included in the `b_count_2`, which in the end is the information I require. And BTW, this answer is much more about the XY problem, since, being open to alternative methods and having evaluated them, they do not address the question.

Comment: Feel free to conclude that way. It's absolutely your right to withhold acceptance of an answer. Equally, the thread is here for anyone else interested. You may get other answers more acceptable to you. You could also air the question on Statalist, but if you do please cross-reference this thread. As already commented, the argument about # of periods is not in your favour as with longer periods you need _thousands_ of extra variables.